# pyspark structured streaming exiting with error socket.timeout: timed out

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I have written a simple kafka pyspark structured streaming., by reading the kafka topic and print each event's partition and offset id using pyspark foreach function. But program is failing after reading few offsets.

```
class RowPrinter:
    def open(self, partition_id, epoch_id):
        print("Opened %d, %d" % (partition_id, epoch_id))
        return True

    def process(self, row):
        print("partition: ", row[4], "offset:", row[5])

    def close(self, error):
        print("Closed with error: %s" % str(error))

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Structured Streaming ").master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
df = spark.readStream.format("kafka").option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "XX.XX.XX.XX:9092,XX.XX.XX.XX.XX:9092").option("subscribe", "log_pst").option("failOnDataLoss", False).load()
test_df = df.selectExpr("topic", "key", "value", "timestamp", "partition", "offset")
query = test_df .writeStream.foreach(RowPrinter()).start()
query.awaitTermination()
```

Running the file using the command:
`spark-submit --jars "D:\kafkaJars\spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12-3.0.0.jar,D:\kafkaJars\kafka-clients-3.0.0.jar,D:\kafkaJars\spark-token-provider-kafka-0-10_2.12-3.0.0.jar,D:\kafkaJars\commons-pool2-2.11.1.jar"  --name example-streaming D:\stream.py`

Getting below o/p and error:

```
Opened 2, 1
partition:  8 offset: 7304836
partition:  8 offset: 7304837
partition:  8 offset: 7304838
Opened 5, 1
partition:  2 offset: 7314983
partition:  2 offset: 7314984
partition:  2 offset: 7314985
partition:  2 offset: 7314986
partition:  2 offset: 7314987
partition:  2 offset: 7314988
partition:  2 offset: 7314989
Opened 8, 1
partition:  0 offset: 7296550
partition:  0 offset: 7296551
partition:  0 offset: 7296552
partition:  2 offset: 7314990
partition:  2 offset: 7314991
partition:  2 offset: 7314992
partition:  2 offset: 7314993
partition:  2 offset: 7314994
partition:  2 offset: 7314995
partition:  2 offset: 7314996
partition:  2 offset: 7314997
Opened 9, 1
partition:  3 offset: 7299538
Opened 3, 1
partition:  5 offset: 7308446
Closed with error: timed out
22/02/14 10:36:23 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 7)
org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\hadoop\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\worker.py", line 605, in main
  File "C:\hadoop\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\worker.py", line 595, in process
  File "C:\hadoop\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\sql\streaming.py", line 1113, in func_with_open_process_close
  File "C:\hadoop\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\sql\streaming.py", line 1105, in func_with_open_process_close
  File "C:\hadoop\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\serializers.py", line 147, in load_stream
    yield self._read_with_length(stream)
  File "C:\hadoop\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\serializers.py", line 164, in _read_with_length
    length = read_int(stream)
  File "C:\hadoop\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\serializers.py", line 593, in read_int
    length = stream.read(4)
  File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\socket.py", line 589, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
socket.timeout: timed out

        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.handlePythonException(PythonRunner.scala:503)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:638)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:621)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:456)
        at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonForeachWriter.close(PythonForeachWriter.scala:66)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.sources.ForeachDataWriter.close(ForeachWriterTable.scala:160)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.DataWritingSparkTask$.$anonfun$run$15(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:477)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.DataWritingSparkTask$$$Lambda$2711/1831861092.apply$mcV$sp(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1433)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.DataWritingSparkTask$.run(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:477)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.V2TableWriteExec.$anonfun$writeWithV2$2(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:385)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.V2TableWriteExec$$Lambda$2433/262393842.apply(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:127)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:463)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$Lambda$2295/1718592933.apply(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1377)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:466)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
22/02/14 10:36:23 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 1.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
22/02/14 10:36:23 ERROR WriteToDataSourceV2Exec: Data source write support org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.sources.MicroBatchWrite@69ff7916 is aborting.
22/02/14 10:36:23 ERROR WriteToDataSourceV2Exec: Data source write support org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.sources.MicroBatchWrite@69ff7916 aborted.
22/02/14 10:36:23 ERROR MicroBatchExecution: Query [id = 610a3553-1eed-4136-8e45-bfe05bd8a079, runId = cb02e06f-abef-4c86-a15a-1aa803055cbb] terminated with error
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Writing job aborted.
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.V2TableWriteExec.writeWithV2(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:413)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.V2TableWriteExec.writeWithV2$(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:361)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.writeWithV2(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:322)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.run(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:329)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.V2CommandExec.result$lzycompute(V2CommandExec.scala:39)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.V2CommandExec.result(V2CommandExec.scala:39)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.V2CommandExec.executeCollect(V2CommandExec.scala:45)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.collectFromPlan(Dataset.scala:3627)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$collect$1(Dataset.scala:2940)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$Lambda$1805/1235661287.apply(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$withAction$1(Dataset.scala:3618)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$Lambda$1806/2028141464.apply(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$5(SQLExecution.scala:100)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$$Lambda$1791/1316458534.apply(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:160)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:87)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$$Lambda$1784/2095663039.apply(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:767)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:64)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3616)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.collect(Dataset.scala:2940)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.$anonfun$runBatch$16(MicroBatchExecution.scala:586)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$Lambda$1783/1737764274.apply(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$5(SQLExecution.scala:100)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$$Lambda$1791/1316458534.apply(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:160)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:87)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$$Lambda$1784/2095663039.apply(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:767)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:64)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.$anonfun$runBatch$15(MicroBatchExecution.scala:581)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$Lambda$1782/1042917224.apply(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter.reportTimeTaken(ProgressReporter.scala:352)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter.reportTimeTaken$(ProgressReporter.scala:350)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.reportTimeTaken(StreamExecution.scala:69)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.runBatch(MicroBatchExecution.scala:581)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.$anonfun$runActivatedStream$2(MicroBatchExecution.scala:223)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$Lambda$1376/397443005.apply$mcV$sp(Unknown Source)
        at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter.reportTimeTaken(ProgressReporter.scala:352)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter.reportTimeTaken$(ProgressReporter.scala:350)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.reportTimeTaken(StreamExecution.scala:69)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.$anonfun$runActivatedStream$1(MicroBatchExecution.scala:191)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$Lambda$1374/52182715.apply$mcZ$sp(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProcessingTimeExecutor.execute(TriggerExecutor.scala:57)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.runActivatedStream(MicroBatchExecution.scala:185)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runStream(StreamExecution.scala:334)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anon$1.run(StreamExecution.scala:245)
```

Can someone tell me why its failing and what configuration have I missed.